# Exit ListView Update Mode after clicking button

Tags: asp.net, listview

I currently am using a listview to edit and update data. When I click edit it goes into the edit format that I want it to. I want to be able to exit the entire edit mode after the update button is clicked. Is this possible?

When I use ListView1.EditIndex = -1 it doesn't go back to the regular view.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        updateButton = true;
        ListViewItem lvl = ListView1.Items[e.ItemIndex];
        var formTitleListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("ListBox1");
        var controlTypeListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("ControlType");
        var formSectionListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("formsection");
        var sortOrderTextBox = (TextBox)lvl.FindControl("SortOrderTextBox");
        var subsectionListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("subsection");
        var subSectionTextBox = (TextBox)lvl.FindControl("SubSectionOrderTextBox");
        var sectionItemListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("sectionitem");
        var sectionSortOrderTextBox = (TextBox)lvl.FindControl("SectionSortOrderTextBox");
        var validationRuleListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("RuleDesc");
        var crossItemListBox = (ListBox)lvl.FindControl("CrossItem");

        var hiddenID = (HiddenField)lvl.FindControl("HiddenPrimaryID");

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RCK-HRSA-DB01;Initial Catalog=ORHP_Dev03182014;User ID=ohitrural;Password=0h!trural"))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ORHP_Dev03182014.Core.Form_Section_SubSection_Item_Rel SET FormID = @FormTitle, FormSectionID = @FormSection, SubSectionID = @SubSection, SectionItemID = @SectionItem, SortOrder = @SortOrder, SectionSortOrder = @SectionSortOrder, SubSectionSortOrder = @SubSectionSortOrder, ValidationRulesetId = @RuleDesc, ControlTypeID = @ControlType, CrossItemID = @CrossItem WHERE DataCollectionPeriodID = " + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + " AND FormSectionSubSectionItemRelID = @FormSectionSubSectionID");
                connection.Open();
                cmd1.Connection = connection;
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormTitle", formTitleListBox.SelectedValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlType", DbNullIfNull(controlTypeListBox.SelectedValue));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormSection", formSectionListBox.SelectedValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortOrder", DbNullIfNull(sortOrderTextBox.Text));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubSection", subsectionListBox.SelectedValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubSectionSortOrder", DbNullIfNull(subSectionTextBox.Text));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionItem", sectionItemListBox.SelectedValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionSortOrder", DbNullIfNull(sectionSortOrderTextBox.Text));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RuleDesc", DbNullIfNull(validationRuleListBox.SelectedValue));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrossItem", DbNullIfNull(crossItemListBox.SelectedValue));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormSectionSubSectionID", hiddenID.Value);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                searchDS = new DataSet();
                dt.Fill(ds);
                searchDS = ds;




                UpdatePanel1.Update();
                ListView1.DataSource = searchDS;                
                ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
                ListView1.DataBind();
                e.Cancel = true;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a `ListView1.DataBind();`, also, remove the empty catch if you want to notice if something goes wrong.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Added ListView1.DataBind() No Luck after update button is clicked, it still stays in edit mode. When I click cancel, ListView1.EditIndex shows the row as empty until I refresh page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `ListView1.DataBind();` and also [`e.Cancel = true;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
// ...
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
ListView1.DataBind()
e.Cancel = true;
// ...
```

Side-note: remove the empty catch if you want to notice if something goes wrong.

Comment: When I click update the first time nothing happens, but when I click it a second time it never goes into the method when debugging but it exits the edit mode. Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem was that I was placing ListView1.DataBind() before ListView1.EditIndex = -1 and not after. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3339242: sorry, i have simply forgotten to add the `ListView1.DataBind()` so the main part of my answer ;)

Comment: One more problem when I click update it updates fine. However, when I click that same row and click cancel it goes back to the original data before the update.

Comment: @user3339242: so the data does not contain the new values? Are you sure that `ListView1.DataBind()` works and also the update? Have you removed the empty `catch`-block or at least set a breakpoint there so that you notice when something went wrong?

Comment: There may be a problem with my datasource. I have updated the code above. Am I assigning and using the datasource correctly?

Comment: @user3339242: apart from the fact that the second DataSet is pointless, why don't you assign `ds` directly? Also, i don't think that this does hurt, but it is confusing anyway: why do you call `UpdatePanel1.Update();` in the middle of the code and not at the end?    Have you handled the `ListView`'s `ItemDataBound` event? Maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks! Everything works the way it should now. I put UpdatePanel1.Update at the end and I took out the dataset and made changes to my datasource in another section.